# Dynamic Form Edit Page : Laravel 5.2

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, laravel-5

this is not a big problem, i believe you all have an idea to solve this. please kindly help.

The matter is i've dynamic form, i can save it into DB and call it again into edit page for each rows and its work fine for me but, idk how to add new row again into DB cause variable that i used cant count the rows. Look at this brother

This is My Table View

```
<tbody>
              <?php foreach($rows as $value): ?>
              <tr>
                <td><textarea class="form-control" rows="3" name="analisa[]" placeholder="Analisa Penyebab" style="resize: none;
                height: 50px">{{$value->analisa}}</textarea></td>
                <td><textarea class="form-control" rows="3" name="tindakan[]" placeholder="Tindakan Perbaikan dan Pencegahan" 
                style="resize: none; height: 50px">{{$value->tindakan}}</textarea></td>
                <td><input class="form-control" type="text" name="pic[] placeholder="PIC" value="{{$value->pic}}"></td>
                <td><input class="form-control" type="date" name="tanggal_pelaksanaan[]" class="picker__table" value="{{$value->tanggal_pelaksanaan}}"></td>
              </tr>
              <?php endforeach?>
            </tbody>
          </table>
<a class="button" href="#" role="button" id="add">&nbspTambah Analisa</a><br><br>
```

Now look at my Javascript

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var i = count($rows);
    $('#add').click(function(){

        $('#tbanalisa tbody').append("<tr>"+"<td>"+i+"</td>"+"<td><textarea class=\"form-control\" rows=\"3\" name=\"analisa[]"+"\" placeholder=\"Analisa Penyebab\" style=\"resize: none; height: 50px\"></textarea></td>"+"<td><textarea class=\"form-control\" rows=\"3\" name=\"tindakan[]"+"\" placeholder=\"Tindakan Perbaikan dan Pencegahan\"style=\"resize: none; height: 50px\"></textarea></td>"+"<td><input class=\"form-control\" type=\"text\" name=\"pic[]"+"\" placeholder=\"PIC\"></td>"+"<td><input class=\"form-control\" type=\"date\" name=\"tanggal_pelaksanaan[]"+"\"></td>"+"</tr>");
    i++; 
    });

});
```

Imagine that i already have 2 rows, now if i change var i = 3; it works fine, now how it automaticly count how many rows i already have ??

Comment: PHP and Javascript are independent languages that are compiled differently so variables from one cannot be accessed by another. PHP is compiled serverside and returns resulting html to the client whereas JS is run in the client browser. There is a few ways you could store the count (ive used element properties for this in the past). However what is the count for? is it number of click on your #add element or is it number of row count?

Comment: hello @JasonJoslin thank you for reply, i used var i to save into array then and for index also. and i used count to count how many rows i already have and in which index i start again. ex : i've 2 rows so the var i count that i already have 2 and now it will add the 3rd row

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php $counter = 0; ?>
```

> You can use a variable say $counter and increment it at each row of the table and access this variable from java script as

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var $counter = <?php echo json_encode($counter); ?>;
        $('#add').click(function(){
        $('#tbanalisa tbody').append("<tr>"+"<td>"+i+"</td>"+"<td><textarea class=\"form-control\" rows=\"3\" name=\"analisa[]"+"\" placeholder=\"Analisa Penyebab\" style=\"resize: none; height: 50px\"></textarea></td>"+"<td><textarea class=\"form-control\" rows=\"3\" name=\"tindakan[]"+"\" placeholder=\"Tindakan Perbaikan dan Pencegahan\"style=\"resize: none; height: 50px\"></textarea></td>"+"<td><input class=\"form-control\" type=\"text\" name=\"pic[]"+"\" placeholder=\"PIC\"></td>"+"<td><input class=\"form-control\" type=\"date\" name=\"tanggal_pelaksanaan[]"+"\"></td>"+"</tr>");

        $counter++;
    });

});
```

Comment: Cant use php in a .js file also you cannot json_encode an integer. json encode is for arrays and objects

Answer (score 1):

You should store your count in an element (with php) so that you can access this value with jquery in the client browser e.g:

`<tbody data-row-count="<?=count($rows); ?>">`

Doesnt have to be the tbody element Im just using it as an example

Now in your jquery you can get current row count and set it again on click:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var i = $(tbody).data('row-count');
    $('#add').click(function(){

        $('#tbanalisa tbody').append("<tr>"+"<td>"+i+"</td>"+"<td><textarea class=\"form-control\" rows=\"3\" name=\"analisa[]"+"\" placeholder=\"Analisa Penyebab\" style=\"resize: none; height: 50px\"></textarea></td>"+"<td><textarea class=\"form-control\" rows=\"3\" name=\"tindakan[]"+"\" placeholder=\"Tindakan Perbaikan dan Pencegahan\"style=\"resize: none; height: 50px\"></textarea></td>"+"<td><input class=\"form-control\" type=\"text\" name=\"pic[]"+"\" placeholder=\"PIC\"></td>"+"<td><input class=\"form-control\" type=\"date\" name=\"tanggal_pelaksanaan[]"+"\"></td>"+"</tr>");
    i++;
    $(tbody).data('row-count', i);
    });
});
```

Probably better to add an ID to your counter element so it has a unique identifier in html and can be accessed in jQuery via the ID. So in your element add `id=RowCounter` then in jQuery you can access with `$('#RowCounter')`

Comment: i can understand it  thank you @JasonJoslin but where should i put <?php $data-row-count = count($rows); ?>

Comment: Replace your tbody element in the first snippet with `<tbody data-row-count="<?=count($rows); ?>">`